# jQuery.extend not working in Internet Explorer, but works in Firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, extend

I am attempting the following:

```
var Class1 = function() {}
Class1.prototype = {
    MyMethod: function() { /* Do Stuff */ }
}

var Class2 = function() {}
Class2.prototype = {
    AnotherMethod: function() { /* Do More Sweet Stuff */ }
}

jquery.extend(true, Class1, Class2);
```

I should now expect to be able to do the following:

```
var c = new Class1();
c.AnotherMethod();
```

In Firefox 3.6 this works just fine.  In Internet Explorer 7 & 8 it says "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Am I misunderstanding how $.extend should work, or is IE behaving badly?

**jQuery Version: 1.3.2**

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be anything to do with your casing on `jquery.extend(...)`?  Shouldn't it be `jQuery.extend(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) should be the target of extending Class1 to include Class2's properties. So, you should instead do:

```
var c;
jQuery.extend(c, Class1, Class2);
```

Unless you truly were intending to do a deep copy, in which case the first parameter should be true, and then the target, followed by the classes:

```
jQuery.extend(true, c, Class1, Class2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need. Now `Class1` should have been extended with the properties of `Class2`

```
jQuery.extend(Class1, Class2);
```

Check [jQuery.extend documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

Answer (score 0):

I am using

```
Class2 = $.extend(true,{},Class1,Class2);
```

And i have same issue of method not found only in IE8. Firefox 3.6 is great same for Opera 10.

On top of everything, the error is inconsistent. When i refresh the page i might or not get the problem again.

I think that in my case it could be related to the way my script are loaded. But still.... IE is causing problem... again.

Comment: I have added $(document).ready() for every extend that i have and it solved my issue on IE8. Right now, all my classes are in separate files and loaded via a lazy load function. For production, everything will be merged and minified.